# Paypal Subscription IPN Custom Variables

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I have an IPN and subscription button working properly. I have a custom variable being sent with the Paypal subscription button form.

I use the custom variable to update the membership expiry date, the custom variable is the members id.

**My question:**
Before I test the IPN over the span of the next couple of days, are custom variables included in the recurring billing cycles?

If not, I'll have to rethink how to automatically update the users membership expiry date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely quicker ways, but I forgot about this problem and the demo recurring billing just incurred the other day.

The custom variable is included in the ipn on the recurring billing cycle in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you passed a `custom` variable in your transaction, it should be return in IPN. See here for the list of [variable](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) that will be return in IPN for a transaction.

Comment: It does pass through the ipn, but because it's a recurring subscription that bills every [x] months, I'm wondering if the custom variable is included in every [x] months when the subscription auto-renews.